# WhiteboxTools not working as QGIS plug in despite following instructions

Tags: qgis

I followed configuration instructions and am attempting to check that WhiteboxTools is configured properly by computing a slope raster from a DEM, but it's not working.

I was expecting to see a slope raster file as output when I attempted to compute slope using WhiteboxTools. I'm not sure why it didn't work, as I followed the installation instructions according to the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJXDBsNbcTg&t=3s

Everything goes smoothly until I get to the part where I use WhiteboxTools to compute slope for a DEM file to test if everything is set up properly. This is the message I see:

```
QGIS version: 3.34.2-Prizren
QGIS code revision: 7d199797fc
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.8.2
GEOS version: 3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.3.1, December 1st, 2023
PDAL version: 2.6.0 (git-version: 3fced5)
Algorithm started at: 2024-01-11T13:07:06
Algorithm 'Slope' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'dem' : 'C:/Users/svr5482/FloodingModelCalibrationProject/04-Spatial_Stats_Samantha/LISFLOOD/norristown_10m_new.asc', 'output' : 'C:/Users/svr5482/Downloads/why.tif', 'units' : 0, 'zfactor' : None }

WhiteboxTools command:
"C:/Users/svr5482/Downloads/WhiteboxTools_win_amd64/WBT/whitebox_tools.exe" -v=true --compress_rasters=True --max_procs=8 --run=Slope --dem="C:\Users\svr5482\FloodingModelCalibrationProject\04-Spatial_Stats_Samantha\LISFLOOD\norristown_10m_new.asc" --units="degrees" --output="C:\Users\svr5482\Downloads\why.tif"
WhiteboxTools output:
****************************
* Welcome to Slope *
* Powered by WhiteboxTools *
* www.whiteboxgeo.com *
****************************
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ParseFloatError { kind: Invalid }', whitebox-raster\src\arcascii_raster.rs:92:69
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Process returned error code 101
Execution completed in 1.97 seconds
Results:
{'output': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/Users/svr5482/Downloads/why.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'windows-1252'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/svr5482/Downloads/why.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

I made sure my computer was updated prior to installation and there were no spaces in any of the file locations. When I compute a slope raster using QGIS it works fine. Any ideas as to what could be going wrong would be appreciated!